# Output folder related to a target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, build

I would like to create a Makefile that builds objects file in different folders depending on which target has been *invoked*.

For example I would like that when I invoke `make` with target `target1` it creates objects in a folder called "`obj/t1`" and "`obj/t2`" when is invoked with `target2`.

I have created this little Makefile:

```
.PHONY=target1 target2 clean setup

SOURCE_ROOT_FOLDER      := src
SOURCES                 := $(shell find $(SOURCE_ROOT_FOLDER) -iname "*.cpp")
OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER         := obj
target1:SUB_OBJ_FOLDER  := t1
target2:SUB_OBJ_FOLDER  := t2

OBJECTS                 = $(subst $(SOURCE_ROOT_FOLDER), $(OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER)/$(SUB_OBJ_FOLDER), \
                          $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

$(OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER)/$(SUB_OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o: $(SOURCE_ROOT_FOLDER)/%.cpp
    @echo "Creating subfolder $(OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER)/$(SUB_OBJ_FOLDER)"
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo "Compiling $< to obj file: $@"
    touch $@

target1:            $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Files $(OBJECTS) have been compiled!

target2:            $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER)

setup:
    @mkdir -p src
    @mkdir -p src/classA
    @mkdir -p src/classB
    @touch src/file.cpp
    @touch src/classA/fileA.cpp
    @touch src/classB/fileB.cpp
```

You can invoke the `setup` target to reproduce a simple fake project in a folder and execute it by yourself.

The output of `make target1` is:

```
Creating subfolder obj/t1
mkdir -p obj//classB/
Compiling src/classB/fileB.cpp to obj file: obj//classB/fileB.o
touch obj//classB/fileB.o
Creating subfolder obj/t1
mkdir -p obj//classA/
Compiling src/classA/fileA.cpp to obj file: obj//classA/fileA.o
touch obj//classA/fileA.o
Creating subfolder obj/t1
mkdir -p obj//
Compiling src/file.cpp to obj file: obj//file.o
touch obj//file.o
Files obj/t1/classB/fileB.o obj/t1/classA/fileA.o obj/t1/file.o have been compiled!
```

So as you can see the variable `SUB_OBJ_FOLDER` is set in the right way inside the recipe, but it seems to be undefined in the target (since `@` is expanded with an empty string) even if the `OBJECTS` variable is expanded correctly in the `target1` rule (as you can check in the final text written in the output).

So I cannot understand why the variable `SUB_OBJ_FOLDER` seems to be not expanded using the parent target that is invoking this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You variable `SUB_OBJ_FOLDER` is indeed set correctly for `target1` and `target2`, but it is not set outside of these targets. this means that the makefile target `$(OBJ_ROOT_FOLDER)/$(SUB_OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o` always expands to `obj//%.o`.

Assuming that you will always use this makefile with exactly one make target (`target1` or `target2`), the solution would be to use the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable to set `SUB_OBJ_FOLDER`. This would be the change in your makefile:

```
#target1:SUB_OBJ_FOLDER  := t1
#target2:SUB_OBJ_FOLDER  := t2
SUB_OBJ_FOLDER := $(MAKECMDGOALS:target%=t%)
```

If you want to support both `target1` and `target2` simultaneously on the command line, it will be a bit more complicated and require an auxiliary makefile that you would include for each target of interest.